# changing image color when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have for example this icon:

[image]

this is the color of the icon when its not clicked .. when i click it it will change the color as shown below:

[image]

what is the best way to achieve that? is there is a way to do it as a font icon and change the color of it? or shall i just change the image when clicked and unclicked?

can someone please tell me the best way to do it...

Comment: if you are using tabBar you can set 2 images for selected and unselected tab, and let the os handle it

Comment: @arash and if not .. i will just change the images?

Comment: @arash that what i'm doing now .. but i want to know the best way of doing this ..

Comment: It looks like you want to change the color of the icon inside the image not the whole image color. For that you can use Button and update the images based on the button states.

Comment: yes on click action of that button you can change its image, `yourButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rendered image

```
var renderedIcon: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate )
imageView.image = renderedIcon
imageView.tintColor = //Normal Color
```

Change the `tintColor` when button clicked.

**OR**

You could set

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "unselectedImage"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named : "selectedImage"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```